# Having trouble using a proxy server

Tags: javascript, node.js, proxy, server

I've been developing in C# .NET, PHP and Javascript/Jquery for years, but I have never had to deal with a proxy server, so research as much as I might, I think I'm missing some basic concept(s) here.

A co-worker created a C# .NET app that sends HTTP requests to a 3rd-party app on a server which returns XML text strings. I'm trying to replicate that behavior with JavaScript and the XMLHttpRequest object. I have been advised I need to use a proxy server to avoid cross-domain problems.

I'm running the TinyWeb server on my development PC. I have node.js installed, running a very simple proxy server with this code:

```
var http = require('http'),
httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
httpProxy.createProxyServer({target:'http://192.n.n.n'}).listen(8022);
```

Port 8022 is just the number I chose, it doesn't have to be that port. If I point a browser to localhost:8022, I see the page hosted on the remote server, the page I expect to see.

I'm building a page, test.html, to test things. That code, as far as I have it so far, is:

```
var url="http://www.localhost:8022";
var UserName="username";
var PassWord="12345678";
var objHTTP = null;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
  objHTTP = new XMLHttpRequest();
  if ( typeof objHTTP.overrideMimeType != 'undefined') {
    objHTTP.overrideMimeType('text/xml');
  }
} 

objHTTP.open("POST", url + "/app.xml", false, UserName, PassWord);
objHTTP.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml" ) ;
objHTTP.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
objHTTP.send();
```

I don't even want it to do anything right now, I just want to prove to myself that I can make a successful connection. But when I go to localhost/test.html, Firebug tells me:

```
NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI: Access to restricted URI denied
objHTTP.send();
```

Execution stops right at the .send(). An alert() on the line just above it displays. An alert() on the line just after it does not.

I've been able to get a proxy working in a couple test situations, so I'm not sure if the proxy is even my problem here, but I don't know how to prove that one way or the other. I admit, I need some schooling on this entire endeavor.